# Should irrelevant parts of questions be removed?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Some (a lot?) of questions start and end with text that is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Things like

> Hi, I'm new to XYZ development, so please be kind.

> Sorry if this is a stupid question, but...

> I hope someone can help me with this. I'm really desperate. Thanks!

Is it allowed, fair (or even encouraged) to delete these? If so, where to draw the line?

Comment: Yes, they don't add anything to the question.

Comment: Just remember that like with all edits, don't just fix this one thing and move on.  Any time you go to edit a question you should fix *all* of the problems with it that you can find.